# Diff EQ: Solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I would like to get some input on the solution I came up with on the following problem:

[image]

There is obviously no way of finding an explicit solution (y= ...) using separation of variables like I did. So would it be correct to leave the answer like this?

Comment: It's what you call an 'implicit solution'. Since an explicit solution isn't possible with elementary functions I think that's the only solution that could be accepted. Also, I uploaded a higher-contrast version of your picture.

Comment: This sort of thing happens quite often.  You have identified all curves $F(x,y,c)=0$ that satisfy the equation.  Given initial conditions, you could find $c$. Really can't go any further, so this sort of answer would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Maybe one of you could leave a (CW?) answer to settle this?

Comment: Thanks all. Yeah leaving an actual answer would be a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your answer against [Wolfram-Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20ln%28x%29%20=%20%28%28y%2b1%29/x%29%5E2%20y%27).

[image]
[image]
[image]

and it appears you have it correct.